# Python - guess longitude and latitude based off dynamic addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopy

I have written a program that uses geopy to find the long and lat of an address. This works 50% of the time, but seems to only work when the address is perfect.

e.g. the address 'Nedumpana', 'Kollam', 'Kerala', 'India' gives a long and lat, but the address 'Manakala', 'Pathanamthitta', 'Kerala', 'India' will not return a result. Obviously this is due to the address not being fully completed, but if I enter this address into Google then the address will autocomplete to find the correct longitude and latitude.

My code is below:

```
import pyodbc
from  geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
cursor = 'SQL Query'

locator = Nominatim(user_agent='myGeocoder')
for row in cursor:
    if cursor is None:
        break
    else:
        address = list(i for i in row if i)
        location = locator.geocode(','.join(filter(None,address[1:4])))
        if location:
            print(str(address) + '\n Latitude = {}, Longitude = {}'.format(location.latitude, location.longitude))
        else:
            print('Could not find coordinates for ' + str(address))
```

How can I make my program still find these longitude and latitude addresses where the address is not complete?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nominatim might be not the best choice for this kind of task. I'd suggest to look at the other geocoders, such as Photon, Google, or Here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are not the first one to ask the question - there is an API: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/example-location-id.html